# How to search for single quote in Oracle11g

Tags: oracle11g

How can I search for a name like `O'Neil` from a table when I use a query like

```
select * from table_name where name like 'O'Neil';
```

then it shows an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape it with the second single quote:

```
select * from table_name where name like 'O''Neil';
```

Since Oracle 10g there is also a quote-operator:

```
select * from table_name where name like q'('O'Neil)';
```

Syntax: `q'c text-to-be-quoted c'`. `c` is a single character (called the quote delimiter). With the «quote operator» apostrophes don't have to be doubled.